# inline-block apply a top effect on blocks when one is higher than others

Tags: css

I would like to build a responsive navbar containing 3 `div` of the same `width` and `height`.

I apply a `inline-block` to each blocks and i get a behavior i don't understand.

The thing is, the third block is composed by 2 lines instead the first and the second ones are composed by 1 line.

The impact of this second line on the third block is like a `top: ?%` would be automatically apply on the first and the second blocks, and i really  don't understand why.

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SfPmF/1/), how would you "align" the 3 blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top`, of course ;)